# Question deletion doesn't notify users composing an answer

Tags: feature-request, answers, notifications, deleted-questions

I was just writing an answer to a [quickly-deleted question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298380/245360).

When you are writing an answer to a question that gets closed, your *Post Your Answer* gets disabled. When you are writing an answer to a question that gets deleted, there is no notification. Only the question gets grayed out and a banner is shown on top of that, but often you don't see that when typing an answer. When you hit *Post Your Answer* when you are finally done, you get an error message...

I would suggest to also disable the button when a question gets deleted and possibly show a banner to the user so they don't write the full answer before seeing it was useless to write any further.

Comment: Especially infuriating on non-FGITW sites where crafting an answer can take *hours*.

Comment: huge problem - i've been hit hard on a couple of 20 minuters. I concur.